# Gulp - ошибки при подключении некоторых плагинов

Tags: node.js, gulp

Осваиваю Gulp.

При подключении плагинов useref, uglify и некоторых других возникают ошибки как на скрине. Эти плагины юзают питон и мне нужно искать его версию подревнее? Просто мне казалось что gulp юзает только node.js или я ошибаюсь?

И что касательно других ошибок или вся беда от питона?
Почему другие плагины (например sass) подключались без проблем.
В общем, в чём разница?

[снимок cmd http://pix.sevelina.ru/images/2016/02/08/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA1.png](http://pix.sevelina.ru/images/2016/02/08/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA1.png)

После переустановки питона на версию 2.7, возникла другая ошибка (скрин 2).
[снимок cmd http://pix.sevelina.ru/images/2016/02/09/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA2.png](http://pix.sevelina.ru/images/2016/02/09/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA2.png)
Качаю с microsoft.com указанную версию .NetFramworka, но он не устанавливается (Win7 x64).

Как установить Gulp правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все очень просто. По всей видимости, один или несколько ваших gulp-плагинов используют модули с *компилируемым кодом*.

Некоторые модули Node.js используют компилируемый C++ код, который выполняется в контексте V8. После традиционной установки таких модулей, происходит их компиляция средствами утилиты `node-gyp` (которая фигурирует в выводе на скриншотах). Эта утилита требует наличия в системе python и компилятора C++ кода. В первом случае у вас не было требуемой версии python, а во втором -- компилятора (да, под Windows для этого часто используется Visual Studio).

Варианты решения проблемы могут быть следующими:

1. Не используйте gulp-плагины, зависящие от компилируемых модулей. В экосистеме gulp достаточно кроссплатформенных плагинов, не зависящих от компилируемых модулей.
2. Не используйте windows-системы (проблем с python и с++ компиляторами под Linux несколько меньше).

Скорее всего, в данном конкретном случае вам может помочь установка Microsft Visual Studio, но гарантировать этого я не стану.